# Read Html Content from uiwebview and load into local folder and retrive to load another webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am working with `UIWebview`. I am able to load `UIWebView` with html file and  because of some need in my project i want to read complete data from `UIWebView`. and I want to display in another `UIWebView`. but my need is I want to save the html data in one local folder what I read alredy. and this save data I want to load in second webview.this is code to load webview and read webview content.How to save in localfolder and retrive from that folder. Can any one help me

**get local html file load into the webview:**

```
[webView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"b_PctureCardHelp" ofType:@"html"]]]];
```

**Read webview Content**

```
NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];

[webView2 loadHTMLString:yourHTMLSourceCodeString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: you can save only html code.. but what about CSS and JavaScripts and Jquery used for the Webview? We can't get them because they are loaded from external paths... the html code we saved will have data with all information with out proper alignment and UI.

Comment: but i am getting complete html as a string "yourHTMLSourceCodeString"

Comment: so again i have complete html file in our hand right? this one i want to save local folder

Answer (score 0):

To Save HTML in local documents folder use this

```
- (void)SaveInfo :(NSString *)HTMLString
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"htmlName.html"];
NSString *helloStr = HTMLString;
NSError *error;
[helloStr writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
}
```

For getting the path and loading

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"htmlName.html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[documentsWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you i have tryied with your answer. i am printing file path i got like /var/mobile/Applications/A49EAEA1-367B-4A04-8334-1FE9F3C9E008/Documents/htmlName.html. then i search in folder its showing like folder cant be fount. how can i confirm is it saved or not

Comment: may i know how can i confirm whether its saved or not

Comment: go to finder and clicl on cmd+shift +g and then enter the path of file

Comment: path will start like this /Users/username/Applications//A49EAEA1-367B-4A04-8334-1FE9F3C9E008/Documents/htmlName‌​.html

Comment: yes i got path like this only: /Users/emantras/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/922D1AFF-D504-431A-812F-64960040A28B/Documents/htmlName.html

Comment: but same message folder not found

Comment: can you paste the new path you got

Comment: /Users/emantras/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/922D1AFF-D504-431A-812F-64960040A28B/Documents/htmlNa‌​me.html

Comment: try unto here /Users/emantras/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/ and then search manually

Comment: i found but its not showing any html data. its storing only <html><head></head><body></body></html>

Comment: NSString *html = [webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];   is this right way to read all cont from webview?

Comment: yes.. but i guess if the web site is using any external CSS or styles then we can not get all code of that page but we will have html information completely to use. may be look of site may change. You can use the above statement

Answer (score 0):

Save Your Html Stirng File to app/Library/Cache

```
NSString *str_html = @"html string";
//yourHTMLSourceCodeString String
NSString *str_lib_path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];    
//Get Library Path
NSString *str_cache_path = [str_lib_path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches"];
//Get Caches Path
NSString *str_file_path = [str_cache_path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.html"];
//yourHTMLSourceCodeString File Path
[str_html writeToFile:str_file_path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
//Save your html string to file path
//then you should find the file in /var/mobile/Applications/(your app uuid)/Library/Caches/file.html
```

Load Html String File

```
NSString *str_lib_path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];    
NSString *str_cache_path = [str_lib_path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches"];
NSString *str_file_path = [str_cache_path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.html"];
//your html string file path
NSString *str_html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:str_file_path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]
//Get your html file from local file
```

Check File Path

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:str_cache_path])    //check caches folder is exist or not
{
    [fm createDirectoryAtPath:str_cache_path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]
    //create caches folder 
} 
//you can also use this method to check the html file is exist or not
```

wish help ~

Comment: i have tryied with your code. i am printing path for testing. iam getting like /var/mobile/Applications/A49EAEA1-367B-4A04-8334-1FE9F3C9E008/Library/Caches/file.html. but its not in folder.

Comment: can you help me to find the saved file in cache

Comment: really strange... maybe you need use NSError to fine some exception or NSFileManager to check the file path folder is exist or not.